How do you make a filtered search bar?
I'm trying to make a website about the history of every single country, so I'm trying to make a search bar to make everything navigable. Here's an example of what I want. Let's say someone's looking for the history of Russia. When they go to the search bar to find Russia, they'll type an R. It will show 5 of the countries with "R" in it (not all of them). My current search bar has everything except the suggestions (the list of 5 countries). I tried doing this, but many bugs popped up and I could not solve them. That's why I need help.
I tried by adding the list of countries, and then making them hidden. When I made them hidden, they weren't visible, but their spacing was still there. I tried deleting the spacing, but it didn't work. I deleted the list of the countries, and the spacing was gone, but there still wasn't any countries. I just stopped working on it and went here.
Here's the code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>National Histories</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <input type="text" id="mySearch" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category">

        <ul id="myMenu">
          <li><a href="afghanistan.html">Afghanistan</a></li>
          <li><a href="albania.html">Albania</a></li>
          <li><a href="algeria.html">Algeria</a></li>
          <li><a href="andorra.html">Andorra</a></li>
          <li><a href="angola.html">Angola</a></li>
          <li><a href="antigua-and-barbuda.html">Antigua and Barbuda</a></li>
          <li><a href="argentina.html">Argentina</a></li>
          <li><a href="armenia.html">Armenia</a></li>
          <li><a href="australia.html">Australia</a></li>
          and so on...
        </ul> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>

CSS:
body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
  
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
  
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}


Where are you storing your country data? Is it coming from a database, a hard-coded list/dictionary, etc..

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@AyesC it’s going to be a list of all the countries, I just need to figure out how to make the search results hidden, without the extra spacing. I’m on my phone right now making this comment, once I get on my computer I’ll then show the code.

Try refering to this W3schols article, it seems to have what you are looking for: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_search_menu.asp
